# php header redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, html, redirect, header

I've created a mail form. A PHP page reads the input, sends it out to a mail and then it should redirect to a certain page. Pretty straight forward, done it before. The mail gets send, but you don't get redirected.

HTML form:

```
<form action="mailversturen.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="Naam" class="inputtype" /><br />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="inputtype" /><br />
<textarea name="bericht" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="buttontype" />
<input type="submit" value="Verstuur" class="buttontype" />
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['naam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['bericht'];

$to = "name@domain.com";
$subject = "Bericht van $name";
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

header('Location: http://www.newlocation.nl/');
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: type exit; after header();

Comment: You probably either have some whitespace before `<?php` or after `?>` or a notice of some kind is being emitted

Comment: Any php error/warning?

Comment: [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php). A really good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@ob_start();` after your opening `<?php` tag.

This turns on output buffering. I use it in combination with all `header(...)` redirects.

Comment: If there was premature output, adding ob_start there would be too late already.